# Initializing a smart pointer to an instance of class and accessing its methods

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, priority-queue

So, I'm trying to implement a priority queue using a sorted list. I have my priority queue class inherit from my sorted list class. My sorted list class works fine when I test its functions in the driver, but I am getting `"Segmentation Fault 11"` when I try testing out my implementation of the priority queue. I ran my code through the CLion debugger and got the error `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"`, which, after some research, seems to be caused by trying to modify data in a null pointer. This is my first time using smart pointers, so I think my issues lie in a misunderstanding with how they're constructed and initialized.

Here's my header file for my `SL_PriorityQueue` class:

```
#ifndef PRIORITY_QUEUE_
#define PRIORITY_QUEUE_

#include "PriorityQueueInterface.h"
#include "LinkedSortedList.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"
#include <memory>

template<class ItemType>
class SL_PriorityQueue : public PriorityQueueInterface<ItemType>
{
  private:
     std::unique_ptr<LinkedSortedList<ItemType> > slistPtr;

  public:
    SL_PriorityQueue();
    SL_PriorityQueue(const SL_PriorityQueue& pq);
    ~SL_PriorityQueue();

    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool dequeue();

    //@throw PrecondViolatedExcept if priority queue is isEmpty
    ItemType peekFront() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
};

#endif
```

Here's the driver I'm using to test my code:

```
#include "../src/Node.cpp"
#include "../src/LinkedSortedList.cpp"
#include "../src/SL_PriorityQueue.cpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SL_PriorityQueue<int> > testing (new SL_PriorityQueue<int>());
    testing->enqueue(7);
    std::cout << testing->peekFront() << std::endl; //I set a break point here, which is where CLion throws the exception
    std::cout << testing->dequeue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << testing->isEmpty() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the function from SL_PriorityQueue.cpp that the CLion highlighted after the exception:

```
template <class ItemType>
bool SL_PriorityQueue<ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
  slistPtr->insertSorted(newEntry);
  return true;
}
```

The error makes me think that when I call insertSorted in the above function, `slistPtr` is still null. My constructor for `SL_PriorityQueue` is empty since it seems that with smart pointers they manage their own memory such that I don't have to set it equal to a null pointer.

I tried making `slistPtr` a shared pointer to see if maybe too many things were pointing to it, but I just received the same error.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: What do you use to initialize that smart pointer? Did you already had a look at [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)?

Comment: BTW, the right way to implement the priority queue - is [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)

Comment: I don't think I used anything to initialize it, which is definitely a big problem haha. And yeah, as I was doing research I came across the heap implementation. I'll take a look at initializing when I get a chance in a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My constructor for SL_PriorityQueue is empty since it seems that with
>   smart pointers they manage their own memory such that I don't have to
>   set it equal to a null pointer.

If I've understood you correctly, you've got a bit mixed up here. Although a unique_ptr will correctly clean up memory it owns, it won't allocate anything itself. The best way of doing so is to use std::make_unique, which you can call from your constructor.

```
template <typename ItemType>
SL_PriorityQueue<ItemType>::SL_PriorityQueue()
   : slistPtr(std::make_unique<LinkedSortedList<ItemType>>())
{
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was definitely it! I had a feeling it had something to do with that. As a sidenote for anyone else who comes across this issue, `std::make_unique` is a C++14 feature.